microtype causes changed spacing with \num from siunitx
When using microtype, it appears that numbers typeset with \num from siunitx are typeset slightly differently compared to the same numbers typed without \num. I tried to set all the reset options to false in order to remove any unwanted effects of font changes. But the effect is still there and quite visible. Compare:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx, microtype}


\sisetup{
    mode=match,
    propagate-math-font = true,
    reset-math-version = false,
    reset-text-family = false,
    reset-text-series = false,
    group-separator={,},
    output-decimal-marker={.},
}

\begin{document}

After thorough consideration, we eventually decided to remove \num{900000} items

\vspace{-1\baselineskip}

After thorough consideration, we eventually decided to remove 900,000 items

\end{document}



Your screenshot shows that the issue isn't confined to the number; the string "we eventually decided to remove" is also affected.

@Mico Isn't that just a side effect of the expansion having to be more aggressive if it cannot be applied to the numbers?

@mickep - I guess my point is similar to the one David Carlisle makes in his answer: Since both \num{900000} and \mbox{900,000} aren't touched by microtype, the issue -- assuming there's one to begin with -- isn't \num but microtype. I add the qualifier "assuming there's one to begin with" deliberately, as I can't see anyone ever being able to notice this in a real document. Put differently, I'm not (yet) convinced that this issue needs to be fixed.

@Mico Typography, particularly with TeX, is often about the small things that few people will ever realize.

@Gaussler - I'm trying to stay pragmatic. Who will ever notice, let along be able to demonstrate, that microtype's work in the line in question has been hobbled because the string 900,000 has (de facto) been placed in an \mbox? A

@Mico I recently added \nums everywhere in a document to get consistent number formats. It altered some line breaks, which caused other parts of the text to flow differently. That was an annoyance to me.

@Gaussler - Not to caste doubt on the severity of the annoyance you experienced, but I think we're talking about two different concerns.

If you add \showoutput you see in the nested box generated by siunitx mathtype is not active
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) o
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) v
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) e
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\hbox(6.44444+1.94444)x32.77788
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 9
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 0
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 0
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 0
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 0
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 0
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) i

But in the second version the digits come from the same slightly shrunk font that is used for the rest of the line
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) o
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) v
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) e
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 9
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) ,
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) 0
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (-20) i

So you would see the same without siunitx if you did
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}

After thorough consideration, we eventually decided to remove \mbox{900,000} items

\vspace{-1\baselineskip}

After thorough consideration, we eventually decided to remove 900,000 items

\end{document}


And can this be “fixed”, if we agree that the second output is preferable?

@Gaussler I don't see how it could be fixed, even in classic tex with no microtype one two will get different spacing to \mbox{one two} if used mid-line like this as the box freezes all glue at its natural size. So iI don't see how microtype can adjust inside a box to adjust for stretching as no stretching occurs.  I suppose it may be possible for this specfic case to ask if siunitx can avoid boxing its output, but that may have other effects that are not all good.

Perhaps the user should be given the choice. @JosephWright, is this something you have considered?
